# How to get substring before first numeric value with TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have following (fictional) entries in a database :

```
ABC-X123
ABC-XY56
XYZ-A12
OP-123
HJK098
```

What would be the best way to get the values before the first numeric value so I would get

```
ABC-X
ABC-XY
XYZ-A
OP-
HJK
```

I know how to do it with functions, but I don't have the option available so if feasible it should be done in the SQL statement.

Comment: Show the code that you have attempted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using case and patindex should work:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66f43/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (str varchar(50))
insert t values 
('ABC-X123'),
('ABC-XY56'),
('XYZ-A12'),
('OP-123'),
('HJK098')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
case patindex('%[0-9]%', str)
    when 0 then str
    else left(str, patindex('%[0-9]%', str) -1 ) 
end
from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66f43/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
|----------|
|    ABC-X |
|   ABC-XY |
|    XYZ-A |
|      OP- |
|      HJK |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `patindex()`:

```
select left(col, patindex('%[^0-9][0-9]%' , col))
```

If the column may not have a number:

```
select (case when col like '%[^0-9][0-9]%' then left(col, patindex('%[^0-9][0-9]%', col))
             else col
        end)
```